# Jquery :not() for <h1> with a span class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have stumbled into the :not() selector on day 12 of Jquery.

I would like to select all the H1s except one, which includes text and a span with class containing more text.  To help you understand the structure, here are some queries and the results:

**query 1:**

```
$('.block > section')
```

Results in:

```
[
<section class=​"businessapproaches">​…​</section>​
, 
<section class=​"abstract">​…​</section>​
, 
<section class=​"workexperience">​…​</section>​
, 
<section class=​"academic">​…​</section>​
, 
<section class=​"skillstable">​…​</section>​
]
```

**query 2**

```
$('.block > section > h1')
```

Results in:

```
[
<h1>​Business Approach​</h1>​
, 
<h1>​Abstract​</h1>​
, 
<h1>​Work Experience​</h1>​
, 
<h1>​Academic Experience​</h1>​
, 
<h1>​…​</h1>​
]
```

As you can see, the last one doesn't have easy text to exclude.  so you know what it is, here it is:

```
[
<h1>​
"Skills Table : "
<span class=​"skillstablevisibility">​Technologies / Compliance / Certifications​</span>​
</h1>​
]
```

For those of you about to suggest using the `:last`, i greatly appreciate it, but I would like to learn how to use the `:not()` selector for this problem, as I will likely be appending an additional section tomorrow, thus negating the `:last`.   The good news it that  after I add the new section, I can guarantee that I still will need to select all sections except the 'Skills Table', so your help will not go to waste!

These are what I have tried thus far:

Attempt by its index:

```
   $('.block > section > h1:not(:'$('.block > section > h1:nth-child(5)')')')
```

Attempt by its name:

```
$('.block > section > h1:not(:"Skills Table : "
    <span class=​"skillstablevisibility">​Technologies / Compliance / Certifications​</span>')')
```

Comment: Try $('.block > section > h1:not(:has("span.skillstablevisibility")))

Comment: I would add a class to that `H1` so you could directly use `:not` on it. Using `:not` in conjunction with child pseudo-selectors (eg `:has` and `:contains`) is expensive. If the H1 has class, you would use `$('.block > section > h1:not(.skills)')`. But if you must, Joy's answer works great.

Comment: Exactly, the selector expression I used is quite expensive. @chris if you have control over the markup creation, then add a class on the `h1` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
$('.block > section > h1:not(:has("span.skillstablevisibility"))')
```

That will not select any `h1` which have a `span.skillstablevisibility` inside it.

**Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/uZjJh/

**Update**

As [@Christian Varga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/551093/christian-varga) commented above, the above selector expression is expensive, so if you have control over markup creation You can add the class to the `h1` itself which will allow selectors like

```
$('.block > section > h1:not(.skillstable)');
```

Which will be better in performance.

And if you cant change the markup You can always use the first one anyway.